# Automated API tests with Postman, Newman on IBM Bluemix/DevOps

Tags: ibm-cloud, postman, devops, newman

I would like to add a test stage in the IBM Bluemix DevOps "Build Deploy" function to test APIs using Postman and Newman but I don't see how to do that. Any advice on where to look?

Answer (score 1):

In the *Build and Deploy* pipeline, if you select the *Add Stage* you can add a new *Test* job to be ran after each update to the source code repository.

When configuring the stage, you can add a "Test" job with the "Simple" tester type. This lets you give shell commands to be executed in the project directory.

Using Newman can be achieved using NPM to manage the package. Providing you have the *newman* package listed in your project dependencies, you could set up an NPM script command to run the tests as below.

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "newman -c tests.json"
},
```

This would allow you to run the following test stage to execute your tests.

```
#!/bin/bash
# invoke tests here
npm install
npm test
```